# Not able to refresh a layout after adding a view(Only Occurs in CustomAdapter)

Tags: java, android, flowlayout

Note: this shouldn't have anything to do with libraries, I just include them for details

Problem:  There is a layout called FlingContainer from this library https://github.com/Diolor/Swipecards.  It takes another layout as a parameter(the card to be flinged), Inside the card I have a button to add tags to the card.  In the CustomAdapter used for the Fling Container I have this code in the GetView method.  I know it works because I can see the TVs getting added in debug mode, they just arent showing up.

What I've tried: I tried doing this in just an activity with no flingContainer and the views are added instantly with no problems.  I tried searching for R.id.addTag from the mainActivity however I get a nullPointer exception, I think this is because addTag is embedded in another layout

Conclusion: Any idea what is going wrong here? how can I get get addView to work in the card?

Thanks

EDIT: here is entire getView

```
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, final ViewGroup parent) {
    final View vi = inflater.inflate(layoutResource, parent, false);
    TextView tv = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.card_one_line);
    flowLayout = (FlowLayout) vi.findViewById(R.id.flow_container);

    final TextView typeTag = new TextView(getContext());
    final TextView typeTag2 = new TextView(getContext());
    TextView addTag = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.addTag);


    typeTag.setText(lines.get(position).getType());

    typeTag.setBackgroundColor(getContext().getResources().getColor(R.color.nice_blue));
    typeTag.setTextColor(getContext().getResources().getColor(R.color.lightening_yellow));
    typeTag.setTextSize(25);
    typeTag.setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5);


    flowLayout.addView(typeTag);


    addTag.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        int i = 0;
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            TextView tv = new TextView(getContext());
            tv.setBackgroundColor(getContext().getResources().getColor(R.color.nice_blue));
            tv.setTextColor(getContext().getResources().getColor(R.color.lightening_yellow));
            String text = "Goofy"+i++;
            tv.setText(text);
            tv.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(
                    ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                    ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            flowLayout.addView(tv);
            parent.invalidate();
            parent.requestLayout();
            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "heyheyhey", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    });


    tv.setText((lines.get(position).getLine()));
    return vi;
}
```

In this pic i am hitting the + button inside the flingcontainer, the g is the default type added outside of the onClick, trying to get onclick to work here
[image]

Comment: You are trying to add views to a view that is suppose to be controlled by an adapter is that correct?

Comment: Yeah! I'm pretty sure thats the case.

Comment: please post the 'getView()' method from the CustomAdapter

Comment: Okay, i added entire getview

Comment: you would like to show a kind of reaction to the user's input. Does the input have an impact on the underlying data or is it more like checking desired items in a list (multiple selection)? Because even if you manage to change the appearance of single layout elements 'onClick', these superficial changes sometimes result in random behaviour (i.e.on scrolling) because of the way adapters are made (recycling layouts for performance reasons)

Comment: Well its just adding a dynamically created textView added to the flowLayout.  So isnt being added to any background data storage etc

Comment: No answer found, the library is broken

Answer (score 4):

**`LayoutParams`**

anytime you create a `View` programmatically do not forget that. just insert `WRAP_CONTENT` and life is good

also use

```
Parent.invalidate();
Parent.requestLayout();
```

the parent here is the `ViewGroup` you are adding to

**EDIT**

make a few adjustment `addTag.setOnClickListener()` is a method which is not dependent on your `getView()` method,so hardcoding reference is not pretty good do this

```
 addTag.setClickable(true);
 addTag.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    int i = 0;
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        TextView tv = new TextView(getContext());
        tv.setBackgroundColor(getContext().getResources().getColor(R.color.nice_blue));
        tv.setTextColor(getContext().getResources().getColor(R.color.lightening_yellow));
        String text = "Goofy"+i++;
        tv.setText(text);
        tv.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        ((ViewGroup)v.getParent()).addView(tv)
        parent.invalidate();// do you know this "parent" guy?
        //i feel it is suppose to be flowlayout
        parent.requestLayout();
        Toast.makeText(getContext(), "heyheyhey", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }
});
```

Comment: Hey i tried your advice and it didnt work, it works when the view is added to a flowlayout in a plain old activity, but not when the flowlayout is inside the fling conatiner.  I know the button works because the toast message pops up.   I've also added pictures and updated code

Comment: also are you sure textView dosent automatically have layoutParams? when i add it in an activity it works without layoutparams

Comment: in my initial code i said something about parent and i see parent in your code, so if i may ask Sir, who is "parent" because to me it is suppose to be your `flowlayout` well check my edit and see if that solves it. also layoutparams tells the parent how a child wants to be treated, so if you are using a custom Viewgroup it is required. also instead of using `ViewGroup.Layoutparams` check if that library has `FlowLayout.LayoutParams` if not stick with what you have @TintinabulatorZea

Comment: parent is passed into the customAdapter like this --- public View getView(int position, View convertView, final ViewGroup parent)

Comment: it still didnt work.  Its very interesting that it works in a plain activity.  I even tried adding a button outside the FlingContainer that did flingContainer.invalidate() and it didnt work:(  I think it is just impossible with this library, i will have to recreate the activity everytime

Answer (score 0):

I met the same issue recently. I've tried a lot of things, and to fix this I called requestLayout() to that child that I just added instead of the parent. In my case, I am adding a child at a certain index. 
`parent.addView(child, index)
parent.getChildAt(index).requestLayout()`